# Video is black when framerate is too low using imageio and Python

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, mp4, python-imageio

I have the following exmaple code:

```
import numpy as np
writer = imageio.get_writer('test.mp4', fps=1)

max = 800
resolution = 256

for idx in range(1, max):
    img = np.zeros((resolution,resolution))
    img[: int((idx / max) * resolution), : int((idx / max) * resolution)] = 255
    img = img.astype(np.uint8)
    writer.append_data(img)

writer.close()
```

The video is just black for `fps == 1`

What am I missing here? I cannot see any clues in the documentation saying I cannot have fps = 1?

*EDIT*

For `fps >= 10` it seems to be fine.

Comment: How are you playing the output?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue with `fps=1` did you find a fix / work around?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I did not. I think your video must have a minimum number of frames to work properly. @gokul_uf