# Why is the last frame always excluded, when converting images into a video?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp4, imread, python-imageio

I have a folder with 225 pictures of maps. So, I compiled it to an mp4 file using `imageio`. Whether it's compiling 10 maps, 150, or all 225, the last picture is always not included in the video.

```
import os
from natsort import humansorted
import imageio

os.chdir(r'folder/path/')
filenames = humansorted((fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.endswith('.png')))
with imageio.get_writer('earthquake_video.mp4', mode='I', fps=2) as writer:
    for filename in filenames:
        image = imageio.imread(filename)
        writer.append_data(image)
    writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your code works fine for 10, 150, or even 225 images – as long as I open the resulting video in Windows Media Player. If I open the video in VLC media player, I get distorted playback, not only skipping the last frame. (I have numbers counting from 0 to 224, so every mistaken frame is noticed.) So, if you use VLC media player, your problem most likely is the one discussed in [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19267443/11089932).

On the `imageio` GitHub issue tracker, there's also [this issue](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/389), linking to [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51067576/11089932), which seems to be same issue as you have. But, still, I think it's the afore-mentioned issue with the VLC media player.

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the workaround from the first linked Q&A working using the [`output_params`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_ffmpeg.html#parameters-for-saving) from `imageio`, i.e. setting `-framerate` or `-r`. So, my workaround here would be to set up a desired `fps` (here: `2`), and a `fps` for the actual playback (in VLC media player), e.g. `30`, and then simply add as many identical frames as needed to fake the desired `fps`, i.e. `30 // 2 = 15` here.

Here's some code:

```py
import os
import imageio

os.chdir(r'folder/path')
filenames = [fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.endswith('.png')]
fps = 2             # Desired, "real" frames per second
fps_vlc = 30        # Frames per second needed for proper playback in VLC
with imageio.get_writer('earthquake_video.mp4', fps=fps_vlc) as writer:
    for filename in filenames:
        image = imageio.imread(filename)
        for i in range(fps_vlc // fps):
            writer.append_data(image)
    writer.close()
```

The resulting video "looks" the same as before (in Windows Media player), but now, it's also properly played in VLC media player.

Even, if that's not YOUR actual problem, I guess this information will help other coming across your question, but actually suffering from the stated issue with the VLC media player.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
imageio:       2.9.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try the solution you wrote later but the video does work properly when played with Windows Media Player.